# How to get $x$, $y$ and $z$ from this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How to find $x$ , $y$ and $z$ from this matrix?

$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & -1 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 5  \\
1 & -1 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{array}$

As usual i began with Gaussian elimination and i've got matrix with three different $z$ values.

$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 3 & -6\\
0 & 0 & -2 & -9  \\
0 & 0 & -2 & -3 \\
\end{array}$

My question is, is it possible to find solution for this matrix because if we eliminate $-2$ from last row we get contradiction $0=15$. Should that mean that matrix has no solution or maybe we could just remove that row because for solving the matrix $rang =4$ is enough? How should i proceed and find solution?

Comment: It means there is no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last $2$ rows say

$-2z=-9$ and $-2z=-3$.

Thus, no solution exists.